C# Httpclient The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception
I am struggling to find the issue with my dotnet core (6.0) C# worker service. My service calls an api endpoint from HTTPS. It was working fine a few days ago and all of the sudden it starts throwing error
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
Inner Exception is
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer
My guess is the endpoint I am accessing is somehow dropping my request.
I asked my server guy and they said they don't block anything.
The weird part is that when I tried to access the api using curl, it works just fine.
The error only shows up when I request from my C# worker Service.
I also check the endpoint ssl from browsers and see if it is valid, The cert is just fine
Here is my specs:
OS: Debian 10
DotNet Ver: 6.0
What I have done so far
1. I check all the many posts in StackOverFlow and mostly forcing to trust cert from ServicePoint Manager etc..but still not working
2. I checked from postman, curl from the same machine and it works fine.
3. I tried to run the same worker service from my windows machine and it works fine.
Any help would be appreciated.

Is it possible that your configuration has changed and so now your application is attempting to access this endpoint via a proxy that is misconfigured or not there (that is bypassed if you use postman/curl)?
If you want to know whether your code is getting far enough to at least have established the underlying TCP connection, you can find out from tools like WireShark where you can monitor your network traffic.  You could also see which party initiated closing/rejecting the connection.

no changes made. no proxy also. but the only thing I notice is that their server ssl certs was recently renewed a few days ago. would that be a possible reason? but still their cert is valid cert according to chrome and firefox.

If the server's certificate has changed and it is now one that your client does not trust, connection establishment will fail unless you take measures in your code to bypass the certificate validation check.  If negotiation fails though, it will be your application that refuses to establish the connection.  Your exception appears to indicate that it is the remote party that has dropped the connection on you.

If you are using a client certificate for this connection and it's no longer trusted by this server, that would be a reason for it to drop you, as well.

I am not using client certs at all, just straight SSL from their endpoint. I tried it from windows machines and it works fine. just having issues in Linux machines
